# auto-complete in yii using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I am new to Yii. I get the values from the Controller. I have stored it in a variable and have performed auto complete function. If I alert the variable, it is showing the values. But in the real code, the auto complete box suggests empty. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

**My view:**

```
<!--Content-->

<div id="content">
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/Nimsoft/create');?>" title="Create New Host" class="btn btn-primary circle_ok" style="text-decoration: none;" >Add New Host to Customer</a>

    <div style="float:right">
                         <?php
                            echo CHtml::link('Upload Customer CSV', array('/Nimsoft/uploadCustomers'), array(
                            'onclick'=>'return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: "iframe", wrapperClassName: "full-size", align: "center" } )',
                            'class'=>'btn btn-primary',
                            'id'=>'upload_link',
                            ));
                         ?>                          
                     </div>
    </div>
    <h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?></h3>
    <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>


    <div class="innerLR">
        <div class="row-fluid">
<?php 

$obj=$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,


    //'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'\'changeTRColor()\'',
    //'itemView'=>'_view',
    'columns'=>array(

                array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                            'name'=>'name',
                                            'value'=>'$data->host_name',
                ),
                array(
                            'name'=>'serviceId',
                            'value'=>'$data->host_serviceid',
                ),

                array(
                                            'name'=>'customer',
                                            'value'=>'$data->customers->cust_name',
                ),
                array(
                                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                                    'template'=>'{delete}{update}',)



),
)); 
$customer_names = array();

foreach ($user as $row) {
    $customer_names[] = array_values($row);
}

json_encode($customer_names);

?>

       </div>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
 //autocomplete
  $(function() {
    var availableTags =<?php echo json_encode($customer_names);?>;

      /*"ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"*/
   alert(availableTags);

    $( "#Search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="Search">Search Customer: </label>
  <input id="Search">
</div>


</body>
</html>

        <div class="separator bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Content END -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!-- // Sidebar menu & content wrapper END -->

<div id="footer" class="hidden-print">
<?php $this->renderPartial('application.views.layouts._footer_inc');  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can anyone update on this please

Comment: Are you getting any errors in js console?

Comment: in the variable I have all the array elements, but my suggest box shows blank

Comment: you are passing as json but your code expects js array. No json object.

Comment: I tried a lot to convert it into JS array, but I cant

Comment: please help me in this. I have been stuck here a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the json to js array, try below code in your code

```
availableTags = $.parseJSON(availableTags);
```